# How do I loop over all the methods of a class in Perl?

Tags: perl, reflection, introspection

How do you loop over all the methods of a class in Perl? Are there any good online references to Perl introspection or reflection?

Comment: For the first question, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910430/how-do-i-list-available-methods-on-a-given-object-or-package-in-perl

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The recommendation Todd Gardner gave to use Moose is a good one, but the example code he chose isn't very helpful.

If you're inspecting a non-Moose using class, you'd do something like this:

```
use Some::Class;
use Class::MOP;

my $meta = Class::MOP::Class->initialize('Some::Class');

for my $meth ( $meta->get_all_methods ) {
    print $meth->fully_qualified_name, "\n";
}
```

See the [Class::MOP::Class docs](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Class-MOP/lib/Class/MOP/Class.pm)  for more details on how to do introspection.

You'll also note that I used Class::MOP instead of Moose. Class::MOP (MOP = Meta-Object Protocol) is the base on which Moose builds. If you're working with non-Moose classes, using Moose to introspect doesn't gain you anything.

If you wanted, you could `use Moose ()` and `Moose::Meta::Class->initialize` instead of CMOP.

Comment: +1: That's neat, I didn't know you could use Class::MOP like that.

Comment: I explain the limitations of this in my answer. Even with an empty class it fails to pick up the methods from UNIVERSAL, and can't pick up any from AUTOLOAD.

Comment: @brian d foy: Using AUTOLOAD is bad, mmmkay?

Answer (score 10):

You can easily get a list of the defined methods of a class using the answers already provided. However, Perl is a dynamic language, which means more methods may be defined later. There really isn't a way to get a list of all of the methods to which any particular class will handle. For a lot more detail on this sort of stuff, I have a few chapters in [Mastering Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527242).

People are giving you (and upvoting) answers without telling you about the limitations.

Adam mentions his [Class::Inspector](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Class-Inspector), but it doesn't really work because it's trying to do something a dynamic language doesn't do (and that's be static :) For instance, here's a snippet where Class::Inspector returns no methods, but I can still call the `VERSION` method (as well as `isa` and `can`):

```
    BEGIN {

package Foo;

our $VERSION = '1.23'
}

use Class::Inspector;

my $methods = Class::Inspector->methods( 'Foo' );

print "Methods are [@$methods]\n"; # reports nothing

print Foo->VERSION, "\n";
```

Here's another case where I can call any method I like, but Class::Inspector only returns `AUTOLOAD` (and still missing `VERSION`, `isa`, and `can`):

```
BEGIN {

package Foo;

our $VERSION = '1.23';

my $object = bless {}, __PACKAGE__;

sub AUTOLOAD { $object }

}

use Class::Inspector;

my $methods = Class::Inspector->methods( 'Foo' );

print "Methods are [@$methods]\n"; # reports only "AUTOLOAD"

print Foo->dog->cat->bird, "\n";
```

Curiously, everyone seems to ignore UNIVERSAL, probably because they don't explicitly handle it since it's only virtually in @ISA. I can add a `debug` method to every class, and Class::Inspector still misses it even though it's a defined method:

```
BEGIN {

sub UNIVERSAL::debug { "Hello debugger!\n" }    
package Foo;
}

use Class::Inspector;

my $methods = Class::Inspector->methods( 'Foo' );

print "Methods are [@$methods]\n"; # still reports nothing

print Foo->debug, "\n";
```

[Class::MOP](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Class::MOP) has the same limitations.

Not every module is going to use AUTOLOAD, but it's not an obscure or rare feature either. If you don't mind that you are going to miss some of the methods then Class::Inspector or Class::MOP might be okay. It's just not going to give you a list of every method you can call on a class or an object in every case.

If you have a class or an object and you want to know if you can call a particular method, use can(). Wrap it in an eval block so can can call can() on things that aren't even objects to still get back false, instead of death, in those cases:

```
if( eval { $object->can( 'method_name' ) } )
    {
    $object->( @args );
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

In the general case, you'll have to inspect the symbol table (unless you use Moose). For example, to list the methods defined in the `IO::File` package:

```
use IO::File;
no strict 'refs';
print join ', ', grep { defined &{"IO::File::$_"} } keys %{IO::File::};
```

The hash `%{IO::File::}` is the symbol table of the `IO::File package`, and the `grep` filters out non-subroutine entries (e.g. package variables).

To extend this to include inherited methods, you have to recursively search the symbol tables of the parent classes (`@IO::File::ISA`).

Here is  a complete example:

```
sub list_methods_for_class {
    my $class = shift;
    eval "require $class";
    no strict 'refs';
    my @methods = grep { defined &{$class . "::$_"} } keys %{$class . "::"};
    push @methods, list_methods_for_class($_) foreach @{$class . "::ISA"};
    return @methods;
}
```

For more info on packages and symbol tables, see the [perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html) man page.

Comment: Not every method has to be defined in the symbol table, and you're missing UNIVERSAL.

Comment: I was wondering, if any of solutions for this question, particularly this one here, generate a new object instance every time the code is called and if it gets recycled or each instance stays in memory until program terminates. Because using reflection/introspection in some other languages like .NET and Java, have to be careful where to instantiate the class object reference else can get new instances per call.

Answer (score 3):

Depends if you mean, any class, or if you were implementing your own. For the latter, I use [Moose](http://www.iinteractive.com/moose/), which offers a very clean syntax for these features. From the cookbook:

```
my %attributes = %{ $self->meta->get_attribute_map };
for my $name ( sort keys %attributes ) {
   my $attribute = $attributes{$name};

   if (   $attribute->does('MyApp::Meta::Attribute::Trait::Labeled')
   # ... keeps on
```

Comment: Note that Moose won't find any attributes unless the class you're introspecting was defined using Moose in the first place.

However, the method introspection, as well as most other bits, will work just fine.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want Class::Inspector->methods('Your::Class').

Nuff said.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just leave this here for when I forget it. This is extremely powerful; too bad it is so out of the way that most Perl programmers never get to experience it.

```
package Foo;
use strict;
sub foo1 {};
sub foo2 {};
our $foo3 = sub{};
my $foo4 = "hello, world!";

package Bar;
use strict;

# woo, we're javascript!
(sub {
    *Bar::foo1 = sub { print "hi!"; };
    *Bar::foo2 = sub { print "hello!"; };
    $Bar::foo1 = 200;
})->();

package main;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;      
$Data::Dumper::Deparse = 1;

print Dumper \%Data::Dumper::;
print Dumper \%Foo::;
print Dumper \%Bar::;
```