# Problems with Perl XML-RPC in combination with Perl reflection?

Tags: perl, reflection, xml-rpc

I'm using [Frontier::Daemon](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Frontier%3a%3aDaemon) to build a test library server for Robot Framework test automation framework. I got the test library server working for executing the code locally, but when it runs/executes over XML-RPC, that is when I run into problems. Part of the issue might also be because I'm using Perl reflection to execute test commands.

Maybe [RPC::XML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?RPC%3a%3aXML) might be a better fit, but at the time I was developing the server, Frontier::Daemon seemed easier to start off with.

The Perl reflection code was borrowed from threads posted on this site as well as Wikipedia's page on code reflection (Perl section).

The code is hosted at [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/plrobotremoteserver/), you can [browse the code](http://code.google.com/p/plrobotremoteserver/source/browse/trunk) or check it out for review.  The issue is [described in more detail at the project site](http://code.google.com/p/plrobotremoteserver/wiki/DevelopmentNotesAndIssues).

I was hoping the Perl developer community could give me some pointers on the source of the problem and how to fix it.

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Can you do anything to present a standalone example of your problem?  I have no idea what you mean by "Perl reflection".

Comment: Or at least provide instructions for duplicating the problem?  I got your example server running, but wasn't able to deduce what an example client would look like before getting bored.

Comment: Unless really requested, I'd rather not spend time writing up an XML-RPC client to demo what the server is supposed to do because, at this point, the server isn't working properly anyways. For anyone working with protocols (HTTP, XML-RPC, SOAP, TCP/IP, etc.), I would think they should know how to work with the protocol messaging w/o needing an end-user client. For example, for XML-RPC, you can test the server messaging w/ any plain REST client (there are various browser extensions of this kind). Sorry, splitting up my responses due to character limits per post.

Comment: Sample XML-RPC requests to make, along with what you currently get back & what you are supposed to get back are described on the wiki

http://code.google.com/p/plrobotremoteserver/wiki/DevelopmentNotesAndIssues

There is also local execution output to compare (in non-XML form) what you should get back.

exampleremoteserver.pl is an example of a client (for local execution via the terminal output) as well as a server. For an XML-RPC client to server, you make XML-RPC requests using a REST client, or build your own. Server will return an XML-RPC response back (over HTTP).

Comment: exampleremoteserver.pl also reproduces the problem when you make the XML-RPC requests.

For Perl reflection, the code in robotremoteserver.pm contains it, and shows how it is used with the rest of the server code. Snippets of those code can be found here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021713/how-do-i-loop-over-all-the-methods-of-a-class-in-perl

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)#Perl

Comment: FYI, a final end-user client to my server, would be a www.RobotFramework.org test case that calls a keyword (example library method) through the remote server. I didn't want to go explain all of that as it might be too complicated for this discussion.

Comment: well, I was unable to successfully communicate with the server, whether with XML::RPC, Frontier::Client, or just netcat.  There's clearly something I'm missing, and I have no interest in figuring out how Frontier::Daemon works to learn what it is.  but if you were to provide a simple client script that demonstrated your problem, I'd love to help

Comment: Apparently you need /RPC2 as the request path to talk to the server; got it working now.

Comment: yea, sorry forgot to mention /RPC2 part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things you are missing.  First, Frontier::Daemon calls the "methods" you provide it as simple subroutine calls, but your two provided methods expect to be called as methods of your remote server object.  Change your code to do this:

```
my $svr = Frontier::Daemon->new(
    methods => {
        get_keyword_names => sub { $self->get_keyword_names(@_) },
        run_keyword => sub { $self->run_keyword(@_) },
    },
...
```

to call your methods as they seem to expect.

Second, your get_keyword_names tries to return an array, but the interface you are using seems to only allow a single return value and is calling the methods in scalar context, causing get_keyword_names to return the count of elements in the array.  I think you want to be returning a reference to the array instead:

```
return \@methods;
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixes most of the problems. I had a feeling I didn't start the XML-RPC server correctly. But still have one remaining problem, run_keyword isn't processing arguments correctly. When I run the method directly in Perl, it handles the arguments correctly, but not when it runs from Frontier.

Comment: Direct execution of `$remote_svr->run_keyword("strings_should_be_equal","hello","world");` debug output shows: `method = strings_should_be_equal
RPC args:
hello
world

Comparing 'hello' to 'world'
Return =>
status => FAIL
traceback => Given strings are not equal at ExampleLibrary.pm line 30.

error => Given strings are not equal at ExampleLibrary.pm line 30.

output => Given strings are not equal at ExampleLibrary.pm line 30.`

Comment: but same call executed over Frontier has this debug output: `method = strings_should_be_equal
RPC args:
ARRAY(0x1d494bc)

Comparing 'ARRAY(0x1d494bc)' to ''` This results in strings_should_not_be_equal reflected method not doing what it was intended to do. What might need to be fixed in regards to the array/arg list referencing in robotremoteserver.pm for run_keyword?

Comment: @ysth: I've committed the code. Sorry, a bit delayed as I've been busy.

Comment: I've also updated the wiki http://code.google.com/p/plrobotremoteserver/wiki/DevelopmentNotesAndIssues to highlight the remaining problem.

Comment: Oh, it works if I do `Frontier::Client->new(url=>"http://localhost:8270/RPC2")->call("run_keyword","strings_should_be_equal","hello","hello")`, but that produces different xml for the request than you show; apparently you are expecting the arguments to the keyword to be an array: `Frontier::Client->new(url=>"http://localhost:8270/RPC2")->call("run_keyword","strings_should_be_equal",["hello","hello"])`.  Trying that shows the problem.  If that's how you are going to be doing calls, you need `run_keyword => sub { $self->run_keyword($_[0], @{$_[1]}) }`

Comment: That seems to fix the problem. Thanks for all your help, really appreciate it.

Comment: @David: forgot to mention, you'd better check that it is actually an array ref before doing the `@{}` dereference or bad input can kill your server.  just passing run_keyword `eval { @{$_[1]} }` may be good enough for you