# Python dir equivalent in perl?

Tags: python, perl

The `dir` command  in Python 2.7.x lists all accessible 'symbols' from a module.
Is there an equivalent in Perl 5.x to list all accessible 'symbols' from a package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
say for sort keys %Foo::Bar::;
```

You can use

```
*Foo::Bar::sym{SCALAR}
*Foo::Bar::sym{ARRAY}
*Foo::Bar::sym{HASH}
etc
```

to see if the symbol has those a variable of the specified type associated with it.

Comment: From a command line that's something like `env MODULE=Foo::Bar bash -c 'perl -e "use v5.10; use $MODULE; say for sort keys %${MODULE}::"'`

Answer (score 3):

You can do it all yourself by rummaging around in the package's symbol table. But [Devel::Symdump](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Symdump) makes it all a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

For package `h`,

```
package h; 
our $r; 

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%h::;
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Devel::Symdump](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Symdump) package does just that. To demonstrate, here's what its dump of itself:

```
$ perl -M'Devel::Symdump' -e 'print(Devel::Symdump->new("Devel::Symdump")->as_string)'
arrays

functions
    Devel::Symdump::AUTOLOAD
    Devel::Symdump::DESTROY
    Devel::Symdump::_doit
    Devel::Symdump::_inh_tree
    Devel::Symdump::_isa_tree
    Devel::Symdump::_partdump
    Devel::Symdump::_symdump
    Devel::Symdump::as_HTML
    Devel::Symdump::as_string
    Devel::Symdump::diff
    Devel::Symdump::inh_tree
    Devel::Symdump::isa_tree
    Devel::Symdump::new
    Devel::Symdump::rnew
hashes

ios
    Devel::Symdump::ENTRY
packages

scalars
    Devel::Symdump::AUTOLOAD
    Devel::Symdump::BEGIN
    Devel::Symdump::DESTROY
    Devel::Symdump::Defaults
    Devel::Symdump::ENTRY
    Devel::Symdump::MAX_RECURSION
    Devel::Symdump::VERSION
    Devel::Symdump::_doit
    Devel::Symdump::_inh_tree
    Devel::Symdump::_isa_tree
    Devel::Symdump::_partdump
    Devel::Symdump::_symdump
    Devel::Symdump::as_HTML
    Devel::Symdump::as_string
    Devel::Symdump::diff
    Devel::Symdump::import
    Devel::Symdump::inh_tree
    Devel::Symdump::isa_tree
    Devel::Symdump::new
    Devel::Symdump::rnew
unknowns
```

You can also output in HTML or get a list of particular types of symbols (scalars, functions, etc).

Note, however, that AUTOLOADed symbols are not dumped unless they have been loaded. If you want to see all *possible* symbols available, you'll want to look at the documentation and/or source code.

Answer (score 0):

**Python**

I **really** like how in python you can do this:

```
print(dir(my_object))
```

And that will print all the methods you can use on your object.

**Back to Perl**

After looking online for a while and not finding a solution using a standard package, I decided to write my own. ([Devel::Symdump](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Symdump) seems like a nice solution, but it is not in the standard perl library).

Let me know if there is a better way or any updates I can make.

**# --- Install "dir" method --- #**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -l

use v5.32;

sub UNIVERSAL::dir{
   my ($s)   = @_;               # class or object  
   my $ref   = ref $s;
   my $class = $ref ? $ref : $s; # myClass
   my $pkg   = $class . "::";    # MyClass::
   
   no strict 'refs';
   my @keys =
      grep { defined $pkg->{$_}->*{CODE} }
      sort keys %$pkg;

   return @keys if defined wantarray;  

   local $" = ', ';              # join separator
   print "$class: [@keys]";
}
```

**# --- Create a sample class --- #**

```
package MyClass {
   sub new {bless {}, shift}
   sub func1{}
   sub func2{}
}
```

**# --- Usage --- #**

```
# Class method
MyClass->dir;        # MyClass: [func1, func2, new]

# Object method
my $obj = MyClass->new;
$obj->dir;           # MyClass: [func1, func2, new]
print for $obj->dir; # [func1, func2, new]
```

Comment: I found this CPAN module which does it similar: https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Functions